# docker COPY command is not persistent

Tags: docker

I have a docker file with the following lines:

```
WORKDIR /volumes/code/

COPY migrations migrations
COPY templates templates
COPY server.py server.py
COPY restart_db.py restart_db.py
COPY alembic.ini alembic.ini
```

but after the container is up and running and im in that folder, some files are there and other aren't:

```
root@512ac3d735ee:/volumes/code# ls
autoai  config  restart_db.py
```

Even though that the COPY command passed successfully:

```
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /volumes/code/
 ---> Running in c02e5b2ed596
Removing intermediate container c02e5b2ed596
 ---> 682a6cb503b6
Step 4/9 : COPY migrations migrations
 ---> 26820b3fa035
Step 5/9 : COPY templates templates
 ---> f603b8e32dcb
Step 6/9 : COPY server.py server.py
 ---> 28877c2cbe1f
Step 7/9 : COPY restart_db.py restart_db.py
 ---> 6b15df227249
Step 8/9 : COPY alembic.ini alembic.ini
 ---> a8a9891b38fc
```

and the files exist in the same folder. 
for example. `restart_db.py` and `server.py` are in the same folder but only `restart_db.py` is copied to the container.

Note: /volumes/code/ is a mounted directory

Comment: An essential fact that should be mentioned in the question is that you mounted `/volumes/code` as a volume.

Comment: You're right. edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me eventually is:

```
docker volume prune
```

and `y` when prompted .

then running again.

Answer (score 0):

Containers are supposed to be instances of running code that modify data. Data is supposed to be in volumes, not code.

The `/volumes/code` should not be declared as a volume, either via `docker-compose` or with the `VOLUME` command.

Comment: Post the complete Dockerfile (or the complete log for the build as much as you can).

Comment: The above is pretty much the whole docker file. Only "FROM python:3.6-slim" on top and "CMD tail -f /dev/null" on the bottom to keep it running.  I ran it through docker-compose which mounts /volumes/code on other containers as well